# Correct AddNode function but somehing happens when I printf

Tags: c, list, printing, addition

I have tested both the addNode function and the printf loop with different lists and they work fine. But something is wrong with this one because when I print the  list it rints the head and then all the other words are the same with the last given from the user.

This is the addnode(the word is given from the user-I checked it, it works fine)

```
struct list* addNode(struct list* head, char *word){

struct list *curr,*help,*Nhead;

curr=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

curr->sorted=head->sorted;          
if(curr->sorted==false){    
    Nhead=head;
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head=head->next;
    }
    curr->data.word=word;
    curr->prev=head;
    curr->next=NULL;
    head->next=curr;

}
else{
    Nhead=head;
    for(help=head; help!=NULL; help=help->next){        
        if(strcmp(word,help->data.word)<0){             
            break;
        }
    }   
    if(help==NULL){ 
        for(help=head; help->next!=NULL; help=help->next){}
        curr->next=NULL;
        curr->data.word=word;
        curr->prev=help;
        help->next=curr;
    }
    else{
        curr->next=help;
        curr->prev=help->prev;
        curr->data.word=word;
        help->prev=curr;
        if(help!=head){
            help=curr->prev;
            help->next=curr;
        }
        else{
            Nhead=curr;
        }
    }

}   


    return Nhead;
}
```

and this is how i print

```
for(curr=pathWordsH; curr!=NULL; curr=curr->next){
        printf("%s",curr->data.word);
        if(curr->next!=NULL){
            printf("-->");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you read in the words, but I guess this is what happens:

When you take input from the user, you probably use the same char buffer. You assign that char buffer to your list node's `word` and it holds the current word while you're constructing the list. After you are done, all nodes reference the same char buffer, whose contents are the last word the user provided.

You should therefore copy the contents instead of assigning pointers. There are basically two ways of doing this: Either allocate memory to `list->word` for each node or make the `word` entry a fixed-size buffer.

The (non-standard, but widely available) function `strdup` duplicates a string on the heap. So instead of assigning the pointer

```
curr->data.word = word;
```

assign a copy of the contents:

```
curr->data.word = strdup(word);
```

Because you have allocated extra memory, you should free the memory in `word` when you destroy a list node.

Comment: printf("\nEnter selection: \n");
    scanf("%s", cur_word);
This is how I read the word inside a while loop. But I didnt quite catch you. Do I just need to change the code you provided?

Comment: And then `head = addNode(head, cur_word)`, right? All your list nodes will have `list->word == cur_word`, so you end up printing the same value for all nodes. Your `cur_word` is scratch space and you must copy the contents. One way to do so is with `strdup`. Have you tried it?

Comment: As a counter example, if you don't ask for user input in a loop but do something like this: `head = addNode(head, "Apple"); head = addNode(head, "Banana"); head = addNode(head, "Cherry")` and then print the list, it should work. That's because the string literals (in diouble quotes)  are all stored at different memory addresses. Part of the difficulty with pointers in C is to know when you can point to existent memory and when you have to copy the contents.